# singular gradient error with nls in r; how do I know if its the code or the data?

Tags: r, nls

I'm trying to run a non linear regression on this data:

```
Flux<-c(192.09536, 199.47616, 137.63245, 133.60358, -89.28360, -23.17639, -27.14659, 107.25287,  52.72565, NA, 167.43277, 113.59047)
Par<-c(4.166667e-01, 4.347826e-02, 4.583333e-01, 1.845833e+02, 1.122688e+03, 1.059048e+03, 6.384000e+02, 3.326087e+02, 7.094762e+02, 4.180000e+02, 3.953333e+02, 3.998636e+02)
Obs<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
curve1<-data.frame(Flux, Par, Obs)
curve1<-do.call("cbind", curve1)
```

This is the first model I tried, which has worked on some other similar datasets:

```
model1 <- nls(Flux~b*Par/(c+Par)-a, data = curve1, start=list(a=180,
                                                          b=-200, c=800))
```

However for this data model1 gives:

```
Error in nls(Flux ~ b * Par/(c + Par) - a, data = curve1, start =
    list(a = 180, : singular gradient
```

I thought this might be because my starting parameters are wrong so I tried to turn it into a self starting model (I've also tried lots of different starting parameters):

```
model2<-with(curve1, nls(Flux~SSasymp(Par, a, b, c)))
```

This gives the same error. 
However I think I have used SSasymp wrong in this case because it fits incorrect curves to data which I am able to fit model1 to.
I think this is because I've confused R about a, b and c (?). I've read that when using SSasymp: 
b is 'the horizontal asymptote (a) -the response when x is 0' 
while c is the rate constant.

In my original equation in model1 b is the horizontal asymptote, c is the rate constant and a is the response when x is 0.

If I try to write a self starting model to reflect this:

```
model3<-with(curve1, nls(Flux~SSasymp(Par, b, (b-a), c)))
```

I get this error:
    In addition: Warning message:
    In nls(Flux ~ SSasymp(Par, b, (b - a), c)) :
      No starting values specified for some parameters.
    Initializing ‘a’ to '1.'.
    Consider specifying 'start' or using a selfStart model

I am looking for advice on 
1) Is model1 not working because of an error in my code/incorrect starting parameters **or because the model just doesn't fit the data**?

If the latter is the case, is there a way to force R to do its best to fit a non-linear model to it anyway? Ecologically, this should really be a saturating curve.

2) Can I/How do I fit my equation into a self-starting model? Have I just fundamentally misunderstood how to use SSasymp?

Any help is very much appreciated. Apologies if I haven't explained or formatted this very well, this is my first post and I'm not an experienced R user or statistician!

Comment: This error usually happens when you have chosen poor starting estimates or if the estimates have a very poor fit... https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2000-September/008131.html

Comment: When I plot your data (Flux on y and Par on x axis), I get a linear dependency with a negative slope. What do you mean by 'saturating curve'? Furthermore, what is your 'curve1' which you submit to nls?

Comment: Since you didn't provide information on what `curve1` is, your example is unfortunately not reproducible. As a guess, I would suspect that the error message is due to the `NA` entry in `Flux`.

Comment: Sorry about that I should have removed data=curve1 - it is just a dataframe with flux and par and one other column (not relevant here) so I just pasted in the useful columns here as I wasn't sure how to add a dataframe in. Removing the NA unfortunately doesn't make any difference. Cleb - it does look linear but I wanted to fit a nonlinear model to it because at some point a value of PAR has to be reached after which Flux no longer changes. Usually this clearly fits well but here the fluxes at lower-mid values of PAR are unusual, hence it looks like it should just be linear.

Comment: I hope that makes sense. Perhaps it just isn't possible to use nls with this data. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: Ok, so the curve is supposed to saturate at around -100 in this case, is that correct!?

Comment: The data is ordered as its written out - so the flux and Par datasets are paired - if the two columns I pasted in were back in a dataframe, each row would be an observation. I.e.(sorry if this doesn't format) Flux<-c(192.09536, 199.47616, 137.63245, 133.60358, -89.28360, -23.17639, -27.14659, 107.25287,  52.72565, 167.43277, 113.59047)
Par<-c(4.166667e-01, 4.347826e-02, 4.583333e-01, 1.845833e+02, 1.122688e+03, 1.059048e+03, 6.384000e+02, 3.326087e+02, 7.094762e+02, 3.953333e+02, 3.998636e+02)
Obs<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
Alldata<-data.frame(Flux, Par, Obs)
Alldata<-do.call("cbind", curve1)

Comment: (I've just changed the original post as above so curve1 is now a dataframe)

Comment: Adding `trace = TRUE` can be helpful.  In this case, you'll see b is going to negative infinity and c going to positive infinity when the model errors out.

Comment: It runs through with 'model1<-nls(Flux~b*Par/(c+Par)-a, start=list(a=100, b=200, c=-300))', where the NA is removed. However, the function with these fitted values looks very ugly. The only model which worked fine for me was a simple linear fit.

Comment: It doesn't look good does it. I guess I will have to go with a linear fit and just not extrapolate beyond the data range I've got. Thanks a lot for having a look:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
model1<-nls(Flux~b*Par/(c+Par)-a, data = curve1, start=list(a=180, b=-200, c=-2000))
plot(Flux~Par,curve1)
curve(predict(model1,newdata=data.frame(Par=x)),add=TRUE)
summary(model1)
# Formula: Flux ~ b * Par/(c + Par) - a
#
# Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# a  -179.17      22.86  -7.837 5.06e-05 ***
# b  1009.36    2556.44   0.395    0.703    
# c -5651.20   11542.41  -0.490    0.638    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
# Residual standard error: 42.43 on 8 degrees of freedom
# ...
```

Your data is somewhat pathological. Functions of the form

> y = b * x / (c+x)

are concave up when `b < 0` and `c > 0`; they are concave down when `b > 0` and `c < 0`, providing `|c| > max(x)` (otherwise there's a vertical asymptote, as demonstrated in one of the comments). Because your data is "nearly" linear, and there is substantial scatter, the best fit (e.g., the set of parameters a, b, and c which minimize the residual sum-of-squares), is concave down (`c < 0`). So if you start with an estimate of `c < -max(x)`, you get convergence.

Now, I gather from your question that `c` has some physical meaning which requires it to be > 0. The problem here is that your model is over-specified (too many parameters). In a saturating curve, the rate constant is determined from the curvature. But in your case, there is no curvature (or, if any, it is negative), so you cannot determine a rate constant. Mathematically, for `x << c`

> b * x / (c + x) ~ (b/c) * x

in your case the slope is about -0.25, so `b/c ~ -0.25`. But there are infinitely many values of `b` and `c` which yield this ratio. So, while you know a lot about the ratio `b/c`, you know nothing at all about `b` or `c` individually. This is why the standard error in those parameters is so large in the fit above (and the p-values are so high).

The bottom line is that, in this specific case, you have insufficient data to determine a, b, and c separately, with any accuracy.

[Two minor points]

1. The presence of `NA`s in your data has nothing to do with this -
   `nls(...)` removes rows containing `NA`s by default.
2. You don't need the line: `curve1<-do.call("cbind", curve1)`

Comment: Ah Ok I understand. Thanks for explaining that so clearly, much appreciated!